# javascript: move image upon button click

Tags: javascript

I am looking for a simple script to move an image in JavaScript. Code examples from Google search results are not working for me.

Please help.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "move image"?  Move it where?

Comment: What do you exactly mean with "move an image"? That could be anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To directly answer your question, this script will move an image 42 pixels below and 42 pixels to the right of your absolutely-positioned parent (provided that the image was not already in that position).

```
var img = document.getElementById("IDImage");
img.style.position = "absolute"; // You should style this with CSS, not this script
img.style.top = 42 + "px";
img.style.left = 42 + "px";
```

Comment: Thank you palswim!!! this was very helpful and worked right away. You are a great SO citizen.